# Finite Difference implicit scheme

Tags: numerical-methods, finite-difference-method

I'm trying to solve the following PDE numerically using an implicit FD scheme:

\begin{equation}
\frac{\sigma_s^2}{2}\frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial S^2} + \rho \sigma_S \sigma_\alpha\frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial S \partial \alpha} + \frac{\sigma_\alpha^2}{2}\frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial \alpha^2} + \mu_s \frac{\partial V}{\partial S} + \mu_\alpha \frac{\partial V}{\partial \alpha} + \frac{\partial V}{\partial t} - rV
\end{equation}

This raises the following two questions I have not been able to find out yet:

- When substituting the derivatives with FD approximations, is the part $rV$ replaced by $rV_{i,j,k}$ or $rV_{i,j,k+1}$?
- When rewriting FD formula in the form of $V_{k}=AV_{k+1} - C$, are the boundary values needed to calculate $C$ taken from $V_{k+1}$ or $V_k$?

Comment: Can you clarify your time notation: is $k+1$ before or after $k$?

Comment: In my setup $k+1$ is before $k$. More precisely, I express the time dimension in terms of time to maturity $\tau$. Hence, in my code $k=0$ corresponds to $\tau_0=0$ (which corresponds to $t=T$, where $T$ denotes expiration). Similarly, $\tau_{max}=T$ (corresponding to $t=0$).

Comment: Then you need to replace it by $rV_{i,j,k+1}$: if you consider two instants $t$ and $s$, $s>t$, the position $V_t$ earns the rate $r$ from $t$ to $s$ hence it is earned on the value $V_t$.

Comment: As for the boundary values, that would depend on your boundary conditions, they might depend on $V_k$s, $V_{k+1}$s or both.

Comment: alternatively you can get rid of the $rV$ term by solving the PDE for $U = e^{-rt}V$

Comment: @DaneelOlivaw Makes complete sense to me now why to take $V_{k+1}$. While typing the pre-edit version of this comment I also understood your comment related to my second question. Thanks!

Comment: @AntoineConze Could you please explain what would be the benefit of taking that approach?

Comment: Improved accuracy you don't add the extra error that comes from the scheme approximating $e^{-rdt}$ with $1-rdt$ or $1/(1+rdt)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the (Euler) Implicit scheme, the only thing that's taken at the previous time level (the one for which you have the solution already), is the $V_{i,j,k}$ that comes from the time derivative. Everything else in the discretized equation is taken at the next time level. So, for both your questions, it's k+1.